# Would like to hide "|" if elements are not showing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to hide `<li>|</li>` when genres array have no value.
Would I use an `ngIf`/`ngHide` to do this, or would I have to code it into my controller?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-inline"> 
        <li ng-if="genre.name" ng-repeat="genre in genres"><a ng-href="/#/genre/{{genre.id}}">{{genre.name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li ng-if="runtime">{{runtime}}min</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>{{release_date | date}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you might have been confused with my question. Sorry about that. I meant how can I hide "<li>|</li>" when there are no values in genres array.

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` ?

Comment: Have you tried `ng-if="genres.length"`?

Comment: Yes I have but I am not quite sure what to test

Comment: it worked @BennettAdams! Thanks so much for that!

Comment: If `|` is the value from  the object then it should be quiet easy..Also share `genres` array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is check that you have `genres` in your array with the `ngIf` directive, so:

```
ng-if="genres.length"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if condition to remove the | part if there is no value.

ng-if - returns true for real value which exists.
ng-if - returns false for falsy values just like generic if condition does.

Just check add ng-if to the | list item with genres in conditional check. If the genres array is empty it will be considered as Falsy value and ng-if will return false and your | will be hidden.

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-inline"> 
        <li ng-if="genre.name" ng-repeat="genre in genres"><a ng-href="/#/genre/{{genre.id}}">{{genre.name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</a></li>
        <li ng-if="genres.length">|</li>
        <li ng-if="runtime">{{runtime}}min</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>{{release_date | date}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```